# How to change JSON structure in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I need to change JSON structure but I'm struggling how to do it, and also I'm not sure if I need to create a new object or I can just work on the current one?

Anyway this is the JSON I want to change:

```
{
  "start": [
     {"time": 22, "value": 324, "year": 2016},
     {"time": 142, "value": 234, "year": 2016},
     ...
  ],
  "end": [
     {"time": 123, "value": 254, "year": 2016},
     ...
  ]
}
```

And change it to this:

```
{
  "key": "start",
  "values": [
     {"time": 22, "value": 324, "year": 2016}, 
     {"time": 142, "value": 234, "year": 2016},
     ...
  ]
 }, {
  "key": "end",
  "values": [
     {"time": 123, "value": 254, "year": 2016},
     ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp

Answer (score 2):

You can map the object and return the new values

```js
var obj = {
  "start": [
     {"time": 22, "value": 324, "year": 2016},
     {"time": 142, "value": 234, "year": 2016}
  ],
  "end": [
     {"time": 123, "value": 254, "year": 2016}
  ]
}

var result = Object.keys(obj).map( k => {
 return {key : k, values : obj[k]}
}).shift();

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Comment: Though this is the ideal answer, I would have liked if OP was allowed to share his effort.

Comment: Wow! Just in 3 lines. Thanks you very much sir.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, my understanding is you are expecting a "key : value" format. But you JSON is already in that format only.

```
"start": [
     {"time": 22, "value": 324, "year": 2016},
     {"time": 142, "value": 234, "year": 2016}
  ]
```

In the above code, start represents key and the array is value. You can access that array using "object.start".